# Accessing Pyramid database outside of WSGI instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'd like to create a Whoosh index from entries in the database connected to my Pyramid application.  However, I'm not really sure how to access the database outside of application.

So my `models.py` is initialized as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Text,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    Table
    )

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    relationship,
    backref
    )

from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME, FLOAT, TEXT

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
dbBase = declarative_base()
dbBase.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Then in `__init__.py`, there is an example of loading in the models:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from .models import db_session, Recipe
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')

    db_session.configure(bind=engine)
```

my `production.ini` has the engine assignment:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost:3306/database?charset=utf8
```

So main is called when the WSGI process is started, which passes the engine from the .ini file.  But I'd like to access the database through a script that does not rely on the WSGI process.  Can I just assign the engine and bind it to the session in the script?  How does the `extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()` affect the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a section in the Pyramid documentation which deals with writing scripts, however it's buried in the [Command-Line section](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/commandline.html).  The pertinent part is that initializedb.py has been converted into a console script, which creates a script in the `bin` directory.  This is why `models` is imported using relative importing.

This seemed a bit superflous for my needs at the moment, so I still needed something simpler.  The solution was to include:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in my script and then call the script from the directory containing my `production.ini` file with:

```
../bin/python -m myproject.scripts.whooshindex production.ini
```

The `-m` runs the module as a script.  This fixes the relative importing, thereby employing all the benefits of the predefined `initializedb.py` script.

Comment: Nowadays the pyramid docs tell you everything you need to know for using console_scripts properly  as suggested by @madjar - http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#making-your-script-into-a-console-script

Comment: Can we use pshell with a proper .ini file (development.ini or production.ini) then import models' DBSession and so on? That works for me. I've done it.

Answer (score 1):

The `alchemy` scaffold contains an [`initialize` script](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/scaffolds/alchemy/+package+/scripts/initializedb.py) you can use as an example. The setup looks like the following example, that I commented for you.

```
config_uri = argv[1]  # Get config file name from arguments
setup_logging(config_uri)  # In case you want ti use the logging config from the file
settings = get_appsettings(config_uri)  # Get a settings dir from the file
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')  # Setup the engine from the settings
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)  # Configure the session to use the engine
with transaction.manager:  # Do stuff in a transaction
    # Do DB stuff
```

The `ZopeTransactionExtension` just means db work needs to be committed, so your either end your code with `transaction.commit()`, or you wrap it into a `with transaction.manager:`.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to run it though, as I'm getting "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package" with regard to importing ..models.  I've tried running in parent directories and there seem to be __init__.py files in all directories.